# Can I set border-left and border-right simultaneously?

Tags: css

Sometimes I find myself in a situation where I want to define a `border` rule for the left and right side of an element. But honestly, `border-left: solid 1px #999; border-right: solid 1px #999` is little clumsy. It wastes space, I have to apply changes twice and it may or may not be rendered less efficiently.

Is there a way to define horizontal borders or vertical borders in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one go like this:

```
#myDiv
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-width: 0 1px; /*horizontal, vertical*/
}​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52AEP/

Comment: That's the shortest solution I've seen so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
<div id="myDiv">Your Div</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myDiv
{
border-width:0 1px 0 1px;
border-color:#ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border:

> While the border-width, border-style, and border-color properties and
>   even the margin and padding shorthand properties accept up to four
>   values, allowing to set different width, style or color, for the
>   different border, this property only accepts one value for each
>   property, leading to the same border for the four edges.

So you could switch to using separate border-width, border-style, and border-color properties, using their shorthand properties to set per-side styles - but I think you're best off as you have it.

That said, ensure that you're saving your style definition as a CSS class - that can then be re-used across elements, rather than applying these one-by-one in "style" attributes on elements throughout your page.

Answer (score -2):

unfortunately there is not an option in css ... you must write all border params manually.